# A Recursively Defined Set of Strings

Tags: regular-language

Describe the strings in the set $S$ of strings over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ which are defined recursively by:

(1) $a$ is in $S$, and

(2) if $x$ is in $S$, then $ax$ is in *S*, $xb$ is in $S$ and $xc$ is in $S$.

So far I have in $S$:

*a, aa, ab, ac, aaa, aab, aac, aab, abb, acb, aac, abc, acc, aaaa, aaab, aaac, aaab, aabb, aacb, aaac, aabc, aacc, aaab, aabb, aacb, aabb, abbb, acbb, aacb, abcb, accb, aaac, aabc, aacc, aabc, abbc, acbc, aacc, abcc, accc*

My question really is whether or not I using the recursive definition correctly, since I can't seem to pick out a regular pattern. I'm confused because there are three definitions, $ax$, $xb$ and $xc$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Questions on Math.SE get more attention when the poster includes what they have tried)

Comment: Look at some examples of strings in $S$ -- you may notice a pattern...

Comment: A recursive definition is much like a proof by induction.  There is a base case (or cases), which in your problem is $a\in S$. Then there are the rules: if $x\in S$, then also $ax, xb, xc \in S$.  These act like the induction step:  assume $x\in S$ and conclude that these longer strings (longer by one character) must also belong to $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll tell you the answer. A string is in $S$ if and only if it consists of $1$ or more $a$'s followed by $0$ or more $b$'s and $c$'s.

If you look at the strings you got that seems right, right? A formal proof will be by induction.

Comment: That makes sense. I was looking for a very straight-forward pattern. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Start with $a\in S$, then you can append $a$ from left and $b,c$ from right, that's the rule.

The words that can arise this way will be in $S$.

Comment: That's just a rephrasing of the definition. In particular it's a rule for _generating_ the strings in $S$. I believe we want a non-recursive _description_ - a string is in $S$ if and only if...

Comment: Yes. Get a sheet of paper and a pen, and start generating yourself. That's the hint basically. You will get a clearer picture about $S$ then, and probably you could also find the non-recursive description.

Comment: Erm, thanks. I posted an answer including the explicit description several days ago...